# Redirect Webmail traffic through port 80?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, port-forwarding, shared-hosting, port-80

I have set up a website on BlueHost (shared server) and I have set up webmail in a subdirectory.
      But every time I use the url mywebsite.com/webmail, it gets rerouted to mywebsite.com:2095 which the office firewall wont connect to due to a blocked port.
Can anyone assist and advise how I can redirect traffic on the server to port 80?
I have read that the redirect can be done through a .htaccess file but I am not too certain how the rule edit is to be done.
Any assistance is highly appreciated, better approaches are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the port used by your host's webmail app will not be possible. Webmail on cPanel is served through port 2095 (or port 2096 for HTTPS). Making a port change would require full root access to the server. Bluehost won't give you root access since it is a shared hosting server. Non-root access also precludes any sort of server-side port forwarding scheme.

If you want to use webmail, you should install a webmail app into your web space that can function solely as a PHP script and does not require a `root` user installation.

AfterLogic Webmail Lite is an excellent option. Choose to download the **standard package**: http://www.afterlogic.org/download/webmail-lite-php